# I can't buy a streak filter where I live. How do I go about making myself one for my DSLR?

Tags: dslr, filter, diy

Generally used to achieve the anamorphic 'streak' effect.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not on Youtube, so I can't embed it, but there is a [nice tutorial here](http://vimeo.com/25581562) that looks like a simple, and very inexpensive method to achieve the streak filter.  (link is to vimeo)

Basically, you affix a piece of fishing line across the lens.